# Reading a lot of files "at the same time"

Tags: c#, io

I'm using `FileSystemWatcher` in order to catch every `created`, `changed`, `deleted` and `renamed` change over whichever file in a folder.

Over this changes I need to perform a simple checksum of the contents of these files. Simply, I'm opening a filestream and pass it to MD5 class:

```
private byte[] calculateChecksum(string frl)
{
    using (FileStream stream = File.Open(frl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        return this.md5.ComputeHash(stream);
    }
}
```

The problem is according the amount of files I need to handle. For example, imagine I have 200 files created along the time in a folder, and then I copy all of them and paste them on the same folder. This action is going to cause 200 event and 200 `calculateChecksum()` performings.

How could I solve this kind of problems?

Comment: Have you thought about a work pool? As in: add jobs to some execution engine, and let them be processed (on the number of threads available) when they come in. I would think some sort of c# async-await magic would be able to do this in quite a simple manner.

Comment: If opening so many files causes performance problems, you may implement a queue and limit the number of working threads.

Comment: You already have a work pool. Check [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `FileSystemWatcher` handler put tasks to queue that will processed by some worker. Worker can process checksum calc tasks with targeted speed or/and frequency. Probably one worker will be better because many readers can slow down hdd with many read seeks.

Try read about BlockingCollection:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx

and Producer-Consumer Dataflow Pattern
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh228601(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var workerCount = 2;
BlockingCollection<String>[] filesQueues= new BlockingCollection<String>[workerCount];

for(int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
{
    filesQueues[i] = new BlockingCollection<String>(500);

    // Worker
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
        while (!filesQueues[i].IsCompleted)
        {
            string url;

            try
            {
                url= filesQueues[i].Take();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException) { }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
            {
                calculateChecksum(url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// inside of FileSystemWatcher handler

```
    var queueIndex = hash(filename) % workersCount
    // Warning!!
    // Blocks if numbers.Count == dataItems.BoundedCapacity
    filesQueues[queueIndex].Add(fileName);
    filesQueues[queueIndex].CompleteAdding();
```

Also you can make multiple consumers, just call Take or TryTake concurrently - each item will only be consumed by a single consumer. But take into account in that case one file can be processed by many workers, and multiple hdd readers can slow down hdd.

UPD in case of multiple workers, it would be better to make multiple BlockingCollections, and push files in queue with index:

Comment: Yes. It would need a mix: Producer - Consumer thread pattern with a pool of `consumers`. There are `producers` (FileSystemWatcher's events) that produce items to process and there are **several** `consumers` that handle them. The next step would be, how to merge or join operations. So, I need a `consumer` handles `x < max` items at the same time.

Comment: @Jordi, you can make multiple consumers, but be careful it posible make hdd performance hit

Comment: I've not understood the last UPD. "push files in queu with index"?

Comment: @Jordi to prevent situation when one file processing by several workers at the same time, one file must be processed always with the same worker, it is posible if you make BlockingCollection for each consumer and use some rule to select queue for each file

Comment: Ok. By now, I've understood, I need to feed my `BlockingCollection`. The problem now, is that I'm not quite to understand how to develop a `consumer` that looks permanently in this collection and according to the actual elements takes `x` of them from the `BlocingCollection` and process them...

Comment: @Jordi, consumer marked with // Worker comment in my code. I have modified example for multi consumer case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96905/discussion-between-jordi-and-gabba).

Answer (score 0):

I've scketched a *cosumer-producer* pattern to solve that, and I've tried to use a thread pool in order to smooth the big amount of work, sharing a `BlockingCollection`

**BlockingCollection & ThreadPool**:

```
private BlockingCollection<Index.ResourceIndexDocument> documents;
this.pool = new SmartThreadPool(SmartThreadPool.DefaultIdleTimeout, 4);
this.documents = new BlockingCollection<string>();
```

As you cann see, I've created a I treadPool setting concurrency to 4. So, there is going to work only 4 thread at the same time regasdless of whether there is `x > 4` work's units to handle in the pool.

**Producer**:

```
public void warn(string channel, string frl)
{
    this.pool.QueueWorkItem<string, string>(
        (file) => this.files.Add(file),
        channel,
        frl
    );
}
```

**Consumer**:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Index.ResourceIndexDocument document = null;
    while (this.documents.TryTake(out document, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
    {
        IEnumerable<Index.ResourceIndexDocument> documents = this.documents.Take(this.documents.Count);
        Index.IndexEngine.Instance.index(documents);
    }
},
TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
);
```

Comment: The problem I'm facing up now is I need to consume a group of files! `GetConsumingEnumerable()` enumerates me every `string` on the `BlockingCollection`, nevertheless I need to process all of them at the same glance.

Comment: Property "Count"  and Method TryTake with little time out (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd287154%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: try use property "Count"  to take all elements alredy in collection and put it to array or smth.
Also BlockingCollection contains method TryTake if you use it  with little time out in loop you can read all existed. After you get timeout do Take as usal.

Comment: I've changed my consumer. I don't know if it's as you've commented. The problem now is, on `Take` method. It doesn't remove the elements from de collection!